# Openshift-origin not create ha-router

Tags: openshift

I tried to create an OpenShift haproxy router, in openshift origin, with the cli:

```
oadm router router-ha --service-account=router --type="haproxy-router" --subdomain="${name}-${namespace}.op37.dev.procempa.com.br" --replicas=2 --selector='region=infra' --selector='zone=default'
```

But, router not create. I have 2 nodes in region=infra, the error is:

```
2 nodes are available: 1 CheckServiceAffinity, 1 MatchNodeSelector, 2 PodFitsHostPorts.
```

My openshift-origin is:

Version

OpenShift Master:
    v3.7.0+7ed6862
Kubernetes Master:
    v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62

Comment: I'll update the question to add the code formatting, which should make things a bit more readable, will also take a look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK let's take a look, we'll need to understand what the error is with the deployment of the router, which I'm guessing is most likely related to the nodes and their labels. Can you please run each of the commands below and add the output to your question?

```
# Get the nodes, showing what labels they have.
oc get nodes -o wide

# Get the recent deployments.
oc get deploy

# For good measure, let's check some status and recent events.
oc status
oc get events
```

That should provide a lot of diagnostic data to help!

Comment: Hi Dave,  thanks a lot for you answer. On really, I already have a router (default) and I tryed create more 2 pods, but I have only node in this time.  Its sure it is not work.
 I added new host, and problem is solved.

Comment: OK thanks for letting me know @ClaudioRogerioSilveira! Glad you are unblocked :)